# Efficiently scoring words in documents, and calculate a document score

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of words with scores (`word_scores`), and a list of the same words but without the scores (`words`).

I loop through a list of documents; get the word score for each word; calculate a mean score for each document, and append it to a list of document scores.

```
doc_scores = []

for doc in documents:
    scores = []
    for word in document:
        if word in words:
            scores.append(word_scores[word])
    doc_score = np.mean(scores)
    doc_scores.append(doc_score)
```

So... any ideas about how to make this more efficient/faster?

Comment: Don't use `if word in words`, as checking if a value is in a list is O(size of the list). Simply use `if word in word_scores:`, as checking if a key exists in a dict is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

One way to improve your code:

```
for doc in documents:
    scores1 = [word_scores[word] for word in doc if word in word_scores]
    doc_score = np.mean(scores1)
    doc_scores.append(doc_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```py
if word in words:
    scores.append(word_scores[word])
```

you can reduce it to

```py
if word_scores.get(words):
    scores.append(word_scores[word])
```

You avoid searching the word through the list, since a score will exist in the dictionary if the word is in the list anyways.

If you have a large number of words, you can also avoid storing all scores, since you're averaging them out later anyways.

```py
for doc in documents:
    scores, count = 0, 0
    for word in document:
        score = word_scores.get(word, 0)
        scores += score
        count += 1 if score else 0
    doc_score = scores/count
    doc_scores.append(doc_score)
```

Comment: The OP calculates the mean of scores afterwards, this would give a completely different result.

Comment: Thanks. So what does the `0` do here?

Comment: Default value if the word isn't in the dictionary

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Could you please explain why it would give a different result? (Due to the total count of words in `scores` being higher due to all zero values, thereby skewing the mean?)

Comment: It would had a score of 0 for any word of `words` not in the document, which would add many zeros to the values whose mean you want, which will not give you what you want. You only want to include the scores of the words that exist in your document, which your current code does.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille good catch, edited it

Comment: @AbhinavMathur With this edit, do you still think it would add speed?

Comment: OK, but then you have a less efficient and clear version of the original code...

Comment: @DIGSUM edited it, you can try profiling it and share the results

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Thanks for the edit. It sped up things significantly!